# how to change and or check for specific string with distance and semicolon

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to load as many text files as I have in a folder (more than 1000). which I can make it to a large `list` Now I want to check if specific column name exist and I do this

I do the following

```
sapply(my list, function(x) all(c("Transmittance: F112: Light, Sample " ) %in% names(x)))
```

There are many other columns that have the same name but I specifically want the column that have `Transmittance: F*`

Is there any way that I do it? because at the end I want to be able to extract those columns with other columns

Here is a small portion of only one file

```
    ldf<- list(structure(list(`Transmitance Ratio: (F648, Light) / (F648, Heavy)` = c(NA, 
100, 0.768, NA, 0.676, NA, NA, 0.538, 0.482), `Transmitance  Ratio (log2): (F648, Light) / (F648, Heavy)` = c(NA, 
6.64, -0.38, NA, -0.56, NA, NA, -0.89, -1.05), `Transmitance s (Scaled): F648: Light, Sample` = c(NA, 
200, 86.9, NA, 80.7, NA, NA, 69.9, 65), `Transmitance s (Scaled): F648: Heavy, Sample` = c(NA, 
NA, 113.1, NA, 119.3, NA, NA, 130.1, 135), `Transmitance s (Normalized): F648: Light, Sample` = c(NA, 
2e+05, 6.46e+08, NA, 2720000, NA, NA, 25800000, 5380000), `Transmitance s (Normalized): F648: Heavy, Sample` = c(NA, 
NA, 8.42e+08, NA, 4030000, NA, NA, 4.8e+07, 11200000), `Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample` = c(NA, 
2e+05, 6.46e+08, NA, 2720000, NA, NA, 25800000, 5380000), `Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample` = c(NA, 
NA, 3.47e+08, NA, 1660000, NA, NA, 19700000, 4600000), `Transmitance s Count: F648: Light, Sample` = c(NA, 
1L, 44L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 4L, 2L), `Transmitance s Count: F648: Heavy, Sample` = c(NA, 
NA, 44L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("Transmitance Ratio: (F648, Light) / (F648, Heavy)", 
"Transmitance  Ratio (log2): (F648, Light) / (F648, Heavy)", 
"Transmitance s (Scaled): F648: Light, Sample", "Transmitance s (Scaled): F648: Heavy, Sample", 
"Transmitance s (Normalized): F648: Light, Sample", "Transmitance s (Normalized): F648: Heavy, Sample", 
"Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample", "Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample", 
"Transmitance s Count: F648: Light, Sample", "Transmitance s Count: F648: Heavy, Sample"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
)))
```

I am only interested in identifying `Transmitance : F` with whatever extension columns

Comment: "I am only interested in identifying Transmitance : F with whatever extension columns" You sure this is the _only_ requirement?

Comment: Please either accept an answer if it solves the problem you have _stated_ here, or edit your question to incorporate additional requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) grep("^Transmitance : F.+", names(x), value = TRUE))

# [[1]]
# [1] "Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample" "Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample1" "Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample1"
```

To actually extract the columns, not just the name:

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(ldf, function(x) select(x, starts_with("Transmitance : F")))

# [[1]]
#   Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample
# 1                                 NA                                 NA
# 2                           2.00e+05                                 NA
# 3                           6.46e+08                           3.47e+08
# 4                                 NA                                 NA
# 5                           2.72e+06                           1.66e+06
# 6                                 NA                                 NA
# 7                                 NA                                 NA
# 8                           2.58e+07                           1.97e+07
# 9                           5.38e+06                           4.60e+06
# 
# [[2]]
#   Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample1 Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample1
# 1                                  NA                                  NA
# 2                            2.00e+05                                  NA
# 3                            6.46e+08                            3.47e+08
# 4                                  NA                                  NA
# 5                            2.72e+06                            1.66e+06
# 6                                  NA                                  NA
# 7                                  NA                                  NA
# 8                            2.58e+07                            1.97e+07
# 9                            5.38e+06                            4.60e+06
```

If you want all extracted columns to be reduced to a single dataframe, you can use `map_dfc` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(ldf, function(x) select(x, starts_with("Transmitance : F")))
```

`map_dfc` basically applies the function to each element of the provided list and combines the output of all elements into a dataframe with cbind.

**Data:** Modify OP's `ldf` for better demonstration:

```
ldf[[2]] = ldf[[1]]
names(ldf[[2]]) = paste0(names(ldf[[1]]), 1)
```

### Edits

As per OP's additional requirement in the comments, To also extract "Transmitance Ratio" columns, just change the regex for `grep`:

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) grep("^Transmitance (: F|Ratio).+", names(x), value = TRUE))
```

`start_with` in `select` does not take regex, so use `matches` instead:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(ldf, function(x) select(x, matches("^Transmitance (: F|Ratio).+")))

library(purrr)
map_dfc(ldf, function(x) select(x, matches("^Transmitance (: F|Ratio).+")))
```

Comment: can you add one more columns ? fir example `"Transmitance : F"` and `"Transmitance ratio : "`

Comment: @nik further edited my answer... Please refrain from adding additional requirements in the comments, and instead add them to your question. Better yet, accept an answer in this question and ask a new question about any new issues. At this point, I think it's just modifying the regular expression, to match all the columns you want.

Comment: I don't think that I should open another question because they are related. I have been trying to use your solution with no success. this solution works if they have common names while f they don't it fails , I really want to like and accept your solution but if I do so, I cannot solve the problem I have and that is why I am still hesitant

Comment: @nik changing the question should be made via the question and not the comments.  The problem is likely with the data set as there are inconsistencies with spelling and number of spaces.  This is easy to address with regex, but the question doesn't ask about this.

Comment: @nik What I meant is that my solution worked for your question as it is posted now. If you think that my solution does not work for your specific case, it means that you haven't specified _all_ requirements in your question. For instance, my solution worked for `"Transmitance : F"` and `"Transmitance ratio : "`, but it seems that these are not the only requirements, then what else? State them in your question.

Comment: @useR "Transmitance : F" and "Abundances"

Comment: @nik Edit it into the question! not comment! BTW, your data example doesn't actually have "Abundances" as a column name, so you will have to change your sample data as well

Answer (score 1):

This will search the beginning of the string to match the pattern and return the full string

```
lapply(ldf, function(x) grep(names(x), pattern = "^Transmitance : F", value = TRUE))

[[1]]
[1] "Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample" "Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample"
```

To extract these columns, use `grepl` and subsetting

```
lapply(seq_along(ldf), function(x) ldf[[x]][grepl(names(ldf[[x]]), pattern = "^Transmitance : F")])

[[1]]
  Transmitance : F648: Light, Sample Transmitance : F648: Heavy, Sample
1                                 NA                                 NA
2                           2.00e+05                                 NA
3                           6.46e+08                           3.47e+08
4                                 NA                                 NA
5                           2.72e+06                           1.66e+06
6                                 NA                                 NA
7                                 NA                                 NA
8                           2.58e+07                           1.97e+07
9                           5.38e+06                           4.60e+06
```

Comment: does not work. I gave you an example file above, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    lapply(ldf, function(x) grep("Transmitance : F", names(x), value = T))
```